# How many positive integers are there, less than 100,000 that are symmetrical?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many positive integers are there, less than 100,000 that are symmetrical? 
(They are the same from left to right and from right to left when you read them)

example: 12321

Comment: Where did you come across this question, and what have you tried yourself to answer it?

Comment: for every arbitrary number abcd you can create a symmetric abcdcba.  So how many numbere less than 1000 are there?

Comment: its a example of my exam on college. tried and i think i cant do it without help. i think that answer is 9*10*10*10*9= 9^2*10^2

Comment: There are 999 abc so there are 999 abcba.  There are 99 ab so there are 99 abba.    Or there are 9 a.  There are 9 aa.  There are 90 ab so there are 90 aba and 90 abba.  There are 900 abc so there are 900 abcba.  There aren't any abccba as those are more than 100000.  Add them up.

Comment: Ivan, you make a mistake in thinking there are nine choices for the leading digit as well as nine choice for the trailing (units) digit.  Symmetry requires that these digits are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you are looking for is palindrome.

We have $9$ one digit numbers that are palindromes.

We have $9$ two digit numbers that are palindromes. Tthe first digit, in the tens' place, can be any of 1-9, and the second digit has to be the same).

We have $9 * 10 = 90$ three digit numbers that are palindromes. (The first digit, in the hundreds' place, can be any of 1-9, and the middle digit can be any of 0-9).

We have $9 * 10 = 90$ four digit numbers that are palindromes. (The first digit, in the thousands place, can be any of 1-9, and the second digit can be any of 0-9. The other two digits must be the same as the first two digits, in reverse order).

We have $9 * 10 * 10 = 900$ five digit numbers that are palindromes. (The first digit can be any of 1-9, the second digit can be any of 0-9, and the third digit can be any of 0-9. The other two digits must be the first two digits reversed).

Then we see that there are $1098$ palindromes below $100000$.

Answer (score 2):

For every number from $1$ to $999$ we can map $abc$ to $abcba < 100000$.  So that are 999 odd number of digits palindromic numbers.  And for every number from $1$ to $99$ we can map $ab$ to $abba < 100000$.  So there are 99 even number of digits palindromic numbers.  So there are 999 + 99 = 1098 total.